# Place 3 Objects Randomly In 3 Specified Positions in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I place 3 gameobjects in random positions range without any of the object having same position as the other 2? How do I achieve this?

So far..

```
public GameObject[] sprites;
int[] Position = new int[3] { 0, 5, -5 };
int resultSprite1;
int resultSprite2;
int resultSprite3;
int y;
int z;
Vector3 pos;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        resultSprite1 = Position[Random.Range(0, Position.Length)];
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
        pos = new Vector3(resultSprite1, y, z);
        sprites[0].transform.position = pos;

        resultSprite2 = Position[Random.Range(0, Position.Length)];
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
        pos = new Vector3(resultSprite2, y, z);
        sprites[1].transform.position = pos;

        resultSprite3 = Position[Random.Range(0, Position.Length)];
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
        pos = new Vector3(resultSprite3, y, z);
        sprites[2].transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

How to achieve this so that no two objects share same positions. All of them should be independent of one another.

Thanks.

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<int> usedNumbers = new List<int> ();
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R))
    {
        //Since it works on update. You should clear the last list before creating a new one.
        usedNumbers.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Position.Length; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                number = Random.Range (0, Position.Length);
            } while (usedNumbers.Contains (number));

            //You have your unique number here.
            sprites[i].transform.position = new Vector3 (Position[number], 0f, 0f);

            //Do not forget to store your number in usedNumbersList.
            usedNumbers.Add (number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an array index out of range error at //sprites[i].transform.position = new Vector3 (Position[number], 0f, 0f);

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have an array of sprites?

Comment: public GameObject[] sprites; You have your array reference. Make sure you have assigned the sprites from the inspector.